# copy subset of rows from one table to another, filtering on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have the following MySql table containing my raw event data (about 1.5 million rows)

```
userId  | pathId  | other stuff....
```

I have an index on `userId, pathId` (approx 50,000 unique combinations)

During my processing, I identify 30,000 `userId, pathId` values that I don't want, but I do want to keep the original raw table.  So I want to copy all rows into a processed event table, except the rows that match this 30,000 `userId, pathId` values.

An approach I'm considering is to write the 30,000 `userId,PathId` values of the rows I do not want into a temp_table, and then doing something like this:

```
[create table processed_table ...]
insert into processed_table 
   select * from raw_table r 
   where not exists (
       select * from temp_table t where r.userId=t.userid and r.pathId=t.pathId
   )
```

For info, `processed_table` generally ends up being half the size of `raw_table`.

Anyway, this seems to work but my SQL skills are limited, so my question (finally) is - is this the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not the most efficient. [Source](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

> That’s why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS.

Here's an example with `NOT IN`:

```
INSERT INTO processed_table 
SELECT *
FROM raw_table 
WHERE (userId, pathId) NOT IN (
    SELECT userId, pathId FROM temp_table
)
```

And `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO processed_table 
SELECT *
FROM raw_table r
LEFT JOIN temp_table t
ON r.userId = t.userid AND r.pathId = t.pathId
WHERE t.userId IS NULL
```

However, since your table is very small and has only 50,000 rows, your original query is probably fast enough.